# IE: dropdown options are blank if contain character of my custom font

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

In my site I need to display `<select>` with inside just icon.
To accomplish this i created a custom font, like [font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), in which every character is one of my icons.

Then in my CSS i placed this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myIcon';
    src:url('../fonts/myIcon.eot?eengex');
    src:url('../fonts/myIcon.eot?#iefixeengex') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/myIcon.ttf?eengex') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/myIcon.woff?eengex') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/myIcon.svg?eengex#myIcon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.select-with-icon {
    font-family: 'myIcon';
}
```

And in my HTML I filled my `<select>` with options containing unicode representation of the characters:

```
<select class="select-with-icon">
    <option value="myValue1">&#xe606;</option>
    <option value="myValue2">&#xe607;</option>
    <option value="myValue3">&#xe608;</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Now, everything works fine with Chrome and Firefox but, ***unexpectedly***, I have some problems with IE.

Ok with Chrome:

[image: chrome]

Totally blank with IE10 and IE9:

[image]

Last points:

- With IE, if i click on one of the blank options the list disappear and the selected icon is correctly displayed inside my `<select>` so the problem it seems to be only with `<option>`.
- I can't use custom javascript components, just native `<select>`.

EDIT:

I forgot to say in the original question but **with IE11 works fine**.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOzyNr) a codepen to try, I used bootstrap glyphicons and the problem is the same.

Comment: I think IE doesn't allow much CSS styling in the options. Maybe add an `!important` to the end of the style rule in your CSS.

Comment: Quoting from FontAwesome: `Apparently, Adblock Plus can remove Font Awesome brand icons with their "Remove Social Media Buttons" setting. We will not use hacks to force them to display. Please report an issue with Adblock Plus if you believe this to be an error. To work around this, you'll need to modify the social icon class names.` This might be why your characters aren't appearing.

Comment: I tried with `!important` and there is the same problem. I don't have Adblock Plus on my IE, indeed i have on Chrome and FF. Thanks anyway

Comment: Is this on a website or on a computer?

Comment: Put your code into CodePen so others can see it live. Try IE11 - I wonder if it works over there. If so, you could better isolate that the error is something related to the EOT file.

Comment: Your codepen works fine under IE10 using IE tester (I couldn't try under IE9 due to JS issues). They include the font via Bootstrap, maybe you can dig this way and see how they declare the font.

Comment: How are you testing IE10? You have a real version, or using F12 tools? If it doesn't work on a real version I doubt it's anything you can fix with CSS. You will be better off building a JS based select and using a `ul`

Comment: @Chimoo Unfortunately I can't use JS component :(

Comment: @MarcoMercuri that's probably you're only choice. You could use a JS component only for < IE 11 and use native for others, but it sounds like a limitation of the browser you won't be able to fix to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your font declaration looks strange. Try dropping `?eengex` from your `font-face` declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myIcon';
    src:url('../fonts/myIcon.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/myIcon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/myIcon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/myIcon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/myIcon.svg#myIcon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The `.eot` font targets IE9 that you are having problems with. IE10 reads WOFF, along with all the other modern browsers.

Another option would be to use font-awesome as a fallback, as it is well tested in older browsers.

Comment: I tried with no result @staypuftman, however there is the same problem with font awesome.

Comment: Can you put your code up somewhere so I could take a look? Thanks.

Comment: See the orginal question, i added a link.

Comment: CodePen just has the HTML, can you add all your assets?

Comment: That codepen is all you need, i imported bootstrap (with font awesome) and gave `.glyphicon` class to my select to give it the correct font, then in any options i put one character. It is exatly what I did in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

note:Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule with the **WOFF** format (***only*** support for EOT format). go and change it

Comment: I don'èt care about IE8, i can ignore that version, however i have both formats woff and eot.

Comment: ok , you need Moderniz It’s a collection to detect  which run as your web page loads, then you can use the results and make view depending on it

Answer (score 0):

I use font awesome on my projects.

in `<head>` tag I insert this (which i downloaded with the font and inserted in my css folder)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

than in my `<body>` tag i use this:

```
     <p> Follow us on: </p>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i></a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a> </li>
</ul>
```

you need to create also a font folder on your website when you put your awsome fonts.

for me it is working.

Comment: Try to replace `<ul><li></li></ul>` tags with `<select><option></option></select>`.

Comment: I do not need to select. My answer was showing you the solution I have adopted.